# How to simplify this linear program using symmetries?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, symmetry

Let $X,Y$ be random variables over finite sets $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$. In the problem below, $W_{Y|X}$ and $\tilde{W}_{Y|X}$ are conditional probability distribution. The set of all conditional probability distributions is given by $\mathcal{P(Y|X)}$. I have the following linear program.

\begin{aligned}
S(W, c)= \inf\ & \gamma \\
{s.t.}\ & p_{XY}(x,y)\geq 0\ \quad \forall(x,y)\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y} \\
& p_{X}(x) = \sum_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}p_{XY}(x,y)\leq \gamma \quad \forall x\in\mathcal{X}\\
& p_{XY}(x,y)\geq \tilde{W}_{{Y}|{X}}(y|x) - W_{{Y}|{X}}(y|x) \quad\forall (x,y)\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\\
& \tilde{W}_{{Y}|{X}}\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{Y}|\mathcal{X})\\
& \tilde{W}_{{Y}|{X}}(y|x) \leq \zeta(y) \quad\forall (x,y)\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\\
& \sum_{y\in\mathcal{Y}} \zeta(y) = c
\end{aligned}

I am able to solve this numerically for any conditional probability distribution $W_{Y|X}$ and nonnegative real number $c$. I am now given that $W_{Y|X}$ is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1-\delta & \delta \\
\delta & 1-\delta
\end{pmatrix}^{\otimes n}$$

I am trying to run this numerically for large $n$ but this becomes intractable very quickly since I have exponentially many constraints as a function of $n$.

How can I exploit the symmetry of the problem due to the tensor product structure of $W_{Y|X}$ to simplify this linear program?